Vertex AI Nodejs 'filePart' giving me type error
  const base64File = await getFileAsBase64("src/testt.jpg");

  console.log(base64File);

  const filePart = {
    inline_data: {
      data: base64File,
      mimeType: "image/jpeg",
    },
  };

  const textPart = {
    text: `
   exampleeee
    `,
  };

  const request = {
    contents: [{ role: "user", parts: [textPart, filePart] }],
  };

  const resp = await generativeModel.generateContent(request); <----- type error

This is my file and the example is from the site. I dunno why it is causing
rgument of type '{ contents: { role: string; parts: ({ inline_data: { data: string; mimeType: string; }; } | { text: string; })[]; }[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | GenerateContentRequest'.
where have I done wrong here?

You are passing request as a dictionary (JSON object) instead of a string, array of string or Part, or GenerateContentRequest. The simplest solution is to convert request to a string using JSON.stringify(). I would follow the examples in the documentation. This page has a few: https://github.com/google-gemini/generative-ai-js

In TypeScript, you can enforce the FileDataPart type as:
import { VertexAI, FileDataPart } from '@google-cloud/vertexai';

      const filePart: FileDataPart = {
        file_data: {
          file_uri: fileUri,
          mime_type: 'image/jpeg',
        },
      };

or InlineDataPart as:
import { VertexAI, InlineDataPart } from '@google-cloud/vertexai';

      const filePart: InlineDataPart = {
        inline_data: {
          data: base64File,
          mime_type: 'image/jpeg',
        },
      };

